# Comparing a character to a quote or single quote

Tags: bash, shell, unix, compare

I want to compare if a character is equal to a quote or single quote but nothing seems to work...

I have tried assigning a variable and comparing like

```
QUOTE=$(echo -e "\042")
if [[ "$CHAR" == "$QUOTE" ]]
```

Since I am kind of a beginner I've also tried various things inside the if-statement like any of the following:

```
if [ "$CHAR" = "/"" ]
if [ "$CHAR" = '"' ]
if [ "$CHAR" = $'\"' ]
```

The last one I tried because it worked when trying to compare to a newline like

```
[ "$CHAR" = $'\n' ]
```

I also tried with double brackets [[ ... ]] and double equal signs == since I am not sure when to use them but with no luck.

Been sitting for 2 hours trying to find the solution without any progress, please help...

Answer (score 2):

To test for a double quote:

```
if [ "$char" = '"' ]; then
```

To test for a single quote, use:

```
if [ "$char" = "'" ]; then
```

#### Aside

Don't use all capitals for variable names.  The system uses all capitals for its names and you don't want to overwrite one of them accidentally.

Answer (score 2):

Three of these work fine for comparing a character to a double quote, while the last one is syntactically invalid (because it uses `"/""` instead of `"\""`). Fixing that, here they all are:

```
#!/bin/bash
CHAR='"'

QUOTE=$(echo -e "\042")
if [[ "$CHAR" == "$QUOTE" ]]
then
  echo "Method 1 works"
fi

if [ "$CHAR" = "\"" ]
then
  echo "Method 2 works"
fi

if [ "$CHAR" = '"' ]
then
  echo "Method 3 works"
fi

if [ "$CHAR" = $'\"' ]
then
  echo "Method 4 works"
fi
```

When running:

```
$ chmod +x myscript && ./myscript
Method 1 works
Method 2 works
Method 3 works
Method 4 works
```

The obvious answer to why you think they're not working is that the value you're comparing is not a quote or not a single character. This shows the importance of creating a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not to get better answers on SO but because you would narrow the problem down to something else in your script.